# How do I search for a string in a list?

Tags: c#, string, list

I don't know how I can return a list with all the soundfragments that contain the string in the titel.

```
    fragmenten = new List<Geluidsfragment>();
    public List<Geluidsfragment> GetFragment(String p)
    {
        fragmenten.IndexOf(p);            
    }
```

I hope you guys can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`List.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<Geluidsfragment> result = fragmenten.FindAll(f => f.Title.Contains(title));
```

Another option is LINQ's `Enumerable.Where` with `Enumerable.ToList`:

```
result = fragmenten.Where(f => f.Title.Contains(title)).ToList();
```

Comment: @user3197825, don't forget to mark the answer that solved your problem, so that others with similar issues are able to find the solution faster.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a `string Title` property:

```
return fragmenten.Where(f => f.Title.Contains(p)).ToList();
```

You might need to add this to the using section of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: This is what your code gives:     

Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Hilversum.Geluidsfragment>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Hilversum.Geluidsfragment>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\School\SE12\SE12-PracticumopgaveGeluidsfragment\GeluidsfragmentProject\BGExperience.cs 62 27 GeluidsfragmentProject

Comment: @user3197825 add `using System.Linq;` to your code file. `Where` is the extension method defined in that namespace

Comment: The System.Linq doesn't work.
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user3197825 what .net framework version you are using? If it's 2.0 then use solution provided by Tim

Comment: @user3197825, in the project properties window

Comment: It's 2.0 so I'll try to use Tim's solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<Geluidsfragment> requiredList = fragmenten.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(p)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourlist.Where(x => x.property.Contains(value)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is the best option available with lambda expression.

You can use it like:-

> fragmenten.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(title)).ToList()